# Is there a "Find in Files" shortcut in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, file, find, shortcut

Is there a "Find in Files" shortcut in Eclipse, as there is in Visual Studio (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)?

I have looked in these two lists:

- [Eclipse Shortcuts](http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm)
- "Show All Shortcuts" shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks to the other two solutions, but here is the complete answer I was looking for, which addresses how I search all the text within the files, not just types, methods, packages, constructors, and fields:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the "Search" dialog box
- "File Search" tab, if it does not appear, expand the window or use the left/right arrows
- type in the text to search for
- Use "*.java", in my case since I am coding in Java, to search just these files
- Click "Search"

Comment: You can actually get "File Search" to be the default when Ctrl + H is clicked by setting it in the key binding. (goto Windows>Preferences and search for keys and filter by 'file search'. And type Ctrl+H in the Binding section)

Comment: This is, for me, what it was the original question. I don't want the "Search" dialog, I only want "File Search", no matter where I am. It's a nuisance to have to change tabs to find it.

Answer (score 92):

select workspace and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>

Which dialog is selected, depends on which file type is selected in the Project Explorer view. For example, if you selected a .js file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, it will bring up the dialog with the "Javascript Search" tab selected. If you want to search all files, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to select the Project Explorer view, use arrow keys to select a folder above your files, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> (or select a file, whose type doesn't trigger a custom dialog tab).

Comment: Thank you. It's called "Open Search Dialog" for what it's worth. In Visual Studio it's called "Find in Files". They appear to be the same functionality.

Comment: However, you have to split the search by only one of the following: Type, Method, Package, Constructor, Field... I just want to search everything. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @MatthewDoucette When you have the dialog open click the left arrow in the top right of the box and you should be able to find the "File Search" tab. That should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Selecting the "File Search" tab will give you what you seek. Eclipse has special searches for different languages. Funny, the Java Search you are describing is one feature I miss dearly in visual studio :).

Comment: Added more to my answer. Salazaar's answer is also correct. Just depends how you want to do it.

Comment: Shaded and Ahe, the "File Search" tab is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. The "Search" dialog box's default size was too small (for a newcomer like myself) to realize this tab existed.

Comment: hmm.. the answers both Salazaar and I gave should take you directly to the "File Search" tab.

Comment: how do i search for files which contains path and file extention, for e.g (C:\*.jar) ? should return all files which are from c drive and file extension is .jar ?\

Answer (score 22):

If you are using only the File Search, you can Disable all other Searches in the Search Panel (Customize... lower left Corner). Then you have the File Search everytime you Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: Great! Now how do I search all the text within the files, not just types, methods, packages, constructors, and fields?

Comment: I have found the solution, and will edit my original post with it.

Comment: you can also re-bind Ctrl+H to "File Search" instead of "Open Search Dialog". To be honest, I've never found a use for any of the other search tools. Re-binding is an alternative to this element of the solution, but but with the benefit of leaving the other tabs around. Either this option or re-binding would save you the second step above of finding the "File Search" tab.

Comment: really awesome answer, i was looking so far!

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed that button before. I also like the "Remember last used page" check on that popup

Answer (score 20):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the search box
- Click 'Customize' in the lower left
- Checkmark 'Remember last used page'
- Click OK.
- Select the file search tab and do a search

Comment: I hope this reaches the top someday. Simple, best answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the type-specific search (Java, Javascript ...etc) you can use <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>, which opens the search dialog, then click the Search button.

If you simply want to search for all text occurrences in the whole the workspace click the word (or select the text) you want to search then hit <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+G</kbd>. You will directly get all the found occurrences without even using a dialog box.

I find <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+G</kbd> is the best solution because it shows the variable name in different by related files (e.g. Java and XML, or Javascript and HTML) while still having the type-specific search feature available through <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>

You can rebind the <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+G</kbd> to finding text in a project or a working set instead of the whole workspace if that's more appealing to you.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is shortcuts for searching Eclipse, these shortcuts are very useful when we search for particular  html, jsp , xml, java, properties ,class, jar,search file with keywords.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is used open Tag, in that you can select type of file Remote Search, File search, git search, java search, javascript search , etc
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is used to search all files in the current project
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is used to search all files in the workspace

Answer (score 3):

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> . Then choose "File Search" tab.

additional search options

search for resources press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

search for Java types press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Source: [Eclipse: Default to "File Search" Tab in Search Dialog](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/08/eclipse-default-to-file-search-tab-in.html)

- Go to your key bindings Windows > Preferences > General > Keys
- Unbind the Shorcut "Ctrl+H" for the "Open Search Dialog"
- Filter/Search for "File Search" and use the "Ctrl+H" here instead.

Answer (score 2):

I believe adding plug-ins power your needs.

If you install Plug-in named **InstaSearch** it makes your **searching faster** inside **current active working projects.**

*It shows the result as you type.*

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch#.VIp-_5_PGPQ

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, `CTRL + H` opens the Search dialog.

Since I use only Find in Files (and set File name patterns when needed), I clicked on Customize... button on the bottom of the Search dialog. It opens Search Page Selection dialog, where I turned off all other options.

You can also click on Remember last used page in the same dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt+F (Find Text in **Project** -**Customized** ***Key***)

**Note** - Ctrl+Alt+G is for Find text in a workspace, not in a project

## How to customize this Key

Window->Preferance->General->Keys-> Search for 'Find Text in Project'->Type 'Ctrl+Alt+F' in binding ->Apply

**Note** - this will be helpful if the developer is working on multiple project simultaneously.