# Aptana/Eclipse Find Next Shortcut - for Find in Files

Tags: eclipse, aptana

i see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569630/is-there-a-find-in-files-shortcut-in-eclipse).  but i still dont see any way to be able to quickly step through a bunch of search results, making edits, and using a shortcut key to advance to the next result.  the Find Next shortcut only works in the Search Tab window, not in the Editor window, where i have focus, while editing.  I have to keep clicking on the next result and then clicking in the editor window to make my edits.

Seems so basic, i must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl+Alt+G** is a default shortcut to search currently selected text in the whole workspace (`Search>Text>Workspace` from menu).

There are no default key mappings for searching selected text in file and in the current project but I find it very usefull added (**Ctrl+Alt+F**, and **Ctrl+Alt+P** respectively (`Window>Preferences>Keys`))

Comment: thanks.  Ctl+Alt+G might be helpful.  Although i usually want to search a subset of files, which i declare in the Ctl+H search box.

Comment: I also usually use Ctrl+K (or Ctrl+Shift+K) for finding next (or previous) occurrnce of the selected text in the file (it's basic but i probably use this in 80% of my quick searches cases (it could work as kind of navigation as well)).

Answer (score 0):

i now see that Ctl+K is set to do something similar.